# itertools.product - return list instead of tuple

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want `itertools.product` to return a list instead of a tuple.  I am currently doing it by creating my own function like this:

```
def product_list(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield list(prod)  # Yields list() instead of tuple()
```

The code is from the Python docs - I just modified the last line.  This works fine but doesn't seem very clever.

What are the other ways of doing this?  I'm thinking of using something like a `decorator` or wrapping it with my own generator function.  I'm not too familiar with either concepts so would appreciate if someone can show me.

**Edit**
I'm doing something messy like this:

```
for r0 in product_list([0, 1], repeat=3):
    r0.insert(0, 0)
    for r1 in product_list([0, 1], repeat=3):
        r1.insert(1, 0)
        for r2 in product_list([0, 1], repeat=3):
            r2.insert(2, 0)
            for r3 in product_list([0, 1], repeat=3):
                r3.insert(3, 0)
```

so I would prefer my function return a list instead of having to cast it every time.  (I know the code is messy and needs recursion but I will think about that later.  I'm more interested to learn how to do what I described above)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`itertools.product` is a generator, and you can easily chain generators together. Here's a generator expression that changes each tuple yielded by `product` into a list:

```
(list(tup) for tup in itertools.product(iterable1, iterable2, etc))
```

In your example code, you could use the generator expression, or you could use a different approach to add an extra value on to the front of your values while keeping them as tuples:

```
for r0 in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3):
    r0 = (0,) + r0 # keep r0 a tuple!
    for r1 in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3):
        r1 = (1,) + r1 # same here
        # ...
```

Since you don't show what you're using your `rN` variables for, it's impossible to give you a definitive answer as to what would be the best way to go. (It is a bit of a code smell that you have numbered variables.) Indeed, since your loops are simply computing three more `0` or `1` digits, you might be able to get away with a single `product` call, that generates an list of `n` different `r` values in one go:

```
for bits in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3*n):
    rs = [(i,) + bits[3*i:3*i+3] for i in range(n)]
    # do something with the list of r tuples here
```